# How to call the picker view content in a table view?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uipickerview

how to call the picker view content in table view..is there any method to call the picker view content?pls help me...

Comment: A little more explanation of what you're trying to do is needed.

Answer (score 0):

I think you would have used this delegate to put your content into the picker.

```
- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    return yourPickerContentArray;
}
```

I think that yourPickerContentArray will have the content of the picker. why dont you use that array where you want.